# MySQL: Selecting one row per unique column value using another column as priority/order

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a MySQL table with the following rows:

| id | key | branchId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dashboard:title | NULL |
| 2 | dashboard:label | 1 |
| 3 | dashboard:description | NULL |
| 4 | dashboard:description | 1 |

The goal is to return a list of rows with unique `key` while giving priority to rows which have a `branchId`. The expected returned rows are:

| id | key | branchId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dashboard:title | NULL |
| 2 | dashboard:label | 1 |
| 4 | dashboard:description | 1 |

I've tried using `GROUP BY` statements alongside `ORDER BY` but was not successful.

Note that I do not have access to the config server to tweak things like `sql_mode`.

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: This is a simple "Top 1 per Group" task. Have you looked at available solutions?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks [PM 77-1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2055998/pm-77-1) for the comment. This question is indeed associated with "Top 1 per group" tasks.

The answer is to group by `key` with a `MAX()` on `branchId`

```
SELECT `key`, max(branchId) from `table` group by `key`;
```